# Move figure to origin

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have used `PixelValuePositions` to get coordinates from a figure.
But I would like to move the figure, so the origin is in the middle of the figure.

An example could be a circle, where the origin of the circle would be moved to the origin of the coordinate-system.

Which commands should I look at?

Comment: I think we need more details. What is the format of the figure? Do you just want to *display* the figure with axes where the origin is in the new position? Or do you want a set of data like a list of ordered triples with the x and y coordinates shifted so that (0, 0) is the coordinate of the particular pixel? It's also pretty unclear why you `tag`ged this with the `education` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal working example for the case stated in OP:

```
ColorConvert[Rasterize[Graphics[Circle[]]], "Grayscale"]
PixelValuePositions[%, 0, 0.5]
ListPlot[Transpose@(Transpose@% - Mean@%)]
```

> [image]